# reactJS drop-down menu in table, duplicating itself

Tags: reactjs, button, drop-down-menu

I am using dropdown on table. I can get the registration number.
But no matter which record is opened, the menu opens up to the number of records.

Adding the number of records up to the menu.

Although there are 4 menus, the number of entries is up
I'm trying but I couldn't fix the problem

can you help me ?

[image]
[image]

```
    this.state = {
      table_dropdownOpen: false, //modalform açık mı kapalı mı ?
    };
    this.table_dropdownToggle = this.table_dropdownToggle.bind(this);
    table_dropdownToggle ()  {
       this.setState(prevState => ({
       table_dropdownOpen: !prevState.table_dropdownOpen,
      }));
    };
 render() {
    const { isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
          <div className={"animated fadeIn container-fluid"}>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <Card>
                  <CardHeader>
                    <i className="fa fa-align-justify" /> Customer Debt
                  </CardHeader>
                  <CardBody>
                    <Table hover bordered striped responsive size="sm">
                      <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th width={"10"} />
                        <th width={"15"}>No</th>
                        <th style={{ display: "none" }}>User</th>
                        <th style={{ display: "none" }}>Key</th>
                        <th style={{ display: "none" }}>CreatedUserKey</th>
                        <th width={"40"}>Total debt</th>
                        <th width={"40"}>Received amount</th>
                        <th scope={"row"}>Description</th>
                        <th width={"20"}>Payment Date</th>
                      </tr>
                      </thead>

                      <tbody>

                      {items.map(item => {
                        return (
                            <tr key={item.id}>

                              <td >
                                <ButtonDropdown
                                    isOpen={ this.state.table_dropdownOpen }
                                    toggle={  this.table_dropdownToggle }
                                    onClick={ () => console.log(item.id) } >
                                  <DropdownToggle caret >
                                    Process
                                  </DropdownToggle>
                                      <DropdownMenu>
                                    <DropdownItem >New record</DropdownItem>
                                    <DropdownItem >Print all</DropdownItem>
                                    <DropdownItem>Another Action</DropdownItem>
                                    <DropdownItem divider />
                                    <DropdownItem>Another Action</DropdownItem>
                                  </DropdownMenu>
                                </ButtonDropdown>
                              </td>
                              <td>{item.id}</td>
                              <td style={{ display: "none" }}>{item.user}</td>
                              <td style={{ display: "none" }}>{item.debtKey}</td>
                              <td style={{ display: "none" }}> {item.createduserKey} </td>
                              <td>{item.totalDebt}</td>
                              <td>{item.receivedAmount}</td>
                              <td>{item.description}</td>
                              <td>{new Date(item.paymentDate).toLocaleString()}</td>
                            </tr>
                        )
                      })}
                      </tbody>
                    </Table>
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every dropdown is tied to `this.state.table_dropdownOpen`, so if one is open, they are all open.  In order for this to work you need a state variable that holds all of the open values.  I'd use a Map for this:

```
this.state = {
      tableDropDownMap: new Map()
};
...
//component did mount, initialize the map
let updatedMap = new Map()
items.forEach(item => updatedMap.set(item.id, false)
...
<ButtonDropdown
  isOpen={ this.state.tableDropDownMap.get(item.id) }
  onClick={ () => console.log(item.id) } >
```

Then in your onClick you'll eventually have something like (it's been a while since I've used class components, so setState may not be right, but you'll get the gist.

```
onClick={() => {
  let updatedMap = new Map(tableDropDownMap)
  updatedMap.set(item.id, !updatedMap.get(item.id))
  this.setState({tableDropDownMap: updatedMap})
```

Comment: Very thanks,

as you said it was very nice I did. But I can't close the drop-down menu this time.

This means that after you open the menu, the menu does not close after you click empty in the table

Comment: how do I close the drop-down menu

Comment: The onClick code above should get you close.  That will update map, what are you having issues with?

Comment: works seamlessly.
The drop-down menu doesn't just close.
So when I click on an empty area, the menu remains open. does not close.

Comment: Not sure how that component is set up to handle that.  There should be documentation for it

Comment: but your code works very well.
Only the drop down menu needs to be closed. Clicking on empty space does not close.
No more problems.
It was exactly what I wanted, a code structure.
Thank you so much

Comment: The code I provided is just some basic javascript and a common pattern to handle multiple elements, what you're asking is about how the `ButtonDropdown` component specifically handles specific events, and I don't have the answer to that.  You'll have to look at that component's documentation or code.

Comment: I understand. So how should I define code in componentDidMount ()?